# How to pass latent vector to decoder in LSTM Variational Autoencoder

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, autoencoder

I'm trying to write my own LSTM Variational Autoencoder for text, and have gotten an OK understanding of how the encoding step works and how I perform sampling of the latent vector `Z`. The problem is now how I should pass on the `Z` to the decoder. For the input to the decoder I have a start token `<s>`, which leaves the hidden state `h`, and the cell state `c` for the LSTM cell in the decoder.

Should I make both the initial states `h` and `c` equal to `Z`, just one of them, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Using [RepeatVector](https://keras.io/layers/core/) you can repeat the latent output `n` times. Then, feed it into the LSTM. Here is a minimal example:

```
 # latent_dim: int, latent z-layer shape. 
 decoder_input = Input(shape=(latent_dim,)) 

 _h_decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(decoder_input)
 decoder_h = LSTM(intermediate_dim, return_sequences=True)
 _h_decoded = decoder_h(_h_decoded)

 decoder_mean = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)
 _x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(_h_decoded)

 decoder = Model(decoder_input, _x_decoded_mean)
```

It is clearly explained in [Keras documentation](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html).

Comment: Thx for your answer. As far as I understand though, when using a VAE for text generation you want the output of the LSTMs to be fed back as input, essentially removing the possibility for `Z` to be used as inputs, which is what your example shows?

Comment: @Covey The output of the LSTM compare with input and the error backpropagate through the network.